# How to include the result of a groovy script in the body of a HTTP POST request in JMeter?

Tags: json, post, groovy, jmeter, httprequest

With a script groovy, written in a BeanShell PreProcessor, I generate a random JSON object with some parameters. I am not able to include this object created (I've used JsonBuilder in the script) in the body of HTTP POST request in JMeter. 
This is a snippet of my script where I create my JSON object:

```
...
def json = new JsonBuilder();
def root = json parameter1: value1, parameter2: value2, parameter3: value3, parameter4: value4;

bsh.shared.root.process();
vars.put("BODY", root.toString());
```

I want to pass this object in the BODY DATA section of HTTP POST request in JMeter:

```
${BODY}
```

This is the response data that is generated:

```
The request content was malformed:
Unexpected character '$' at input index 0 (line 1, position 1), expected JSON Value:
${BODY}
^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) in the Beanshell Pre-Processor as Groovy and [Beanshell](https://beanshell.github.io/) are different beasts.

For example the `def` keyword you're trying to use [exists in Groovy](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-syntax.html#_keywords) but doesn't exist in Beanshell and if you open [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file you will see the following:

> BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``def json = new JsonBuilder();'' : Typed variable declaration : **Class: def not found in namespace**

As your script fails in the very first line your `${BODY}` variable is not defined and is being sent as it is by the HTTP Request sampler hence you're getting this error.

Switch to the JSR223 PreProcessor, ensure to choose `groovy` from the "Language" dropdown and double check that there are no errors in the *jmeter.log* file.

More information:

- [JMeter Best Practices: Beanshell Scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)